# GPT-4 doesn't follow output format instruction occasionally

Tags: openai-api, gpt-4

I am writing a custom wrapper for OpenAI GPT-4 API. I do the prompting similarly to the ReAct model (Thought, Action, Observation, Final Answer). This is my output format instruction for the agent scratchpad

```
Populate the scratchpad (delimited by the triple quote) to guide yourself toward the answer. For the scratchpad, always choose to follow only one of the situations listed below (inside the triple curly braces) and then end your answer. You CAN NOT populate the Observation field yourself. Always include word "End Answer" at the end of your answer\n\
{{{\
Situation 1: You can ONLY choose ONE action at a time. When you decide you need to use a tool (based on the observations and input question), please follow this format to answer the question:\n\
Thought: you should always think about what to do.\n\
Action: the action to take, should always be one of [${tools.map(
(toolDocumentation) => toolDocumentation.name
)}].\n\
Action Input: the input to the action. Should list the input parameter as this format suggest: "parameter1", "parameter", ...]\n\
End Answer\n\n\
[End Answer Here]

Situation 2: When you don't need to use a tool, please follow this format to answer the question: \n\
Thought: you should always think about what to do.\n\
Final Answer: Provide your final answer for the input question from the input question or the Observation (if it exists).\n\
End Answer\n\n\
[End Answer Here]
}}}\n
```

The idea is to tell GPT-4 to always include "End Answer" at the end of its response so I can parse its output with regex. However, approximately 1/10 times, it fails to include that keyword and messes up my output parser. How can I improve my prompt to keep the result more consistent?

I try setting the temperature to 0, adding many delimeters as OpenAI suggests. But the result keeps being inconsistent